# Не запускается geckodriver во время выполнения cron на Bitrix

Tags: php, selenium, битрикс, cron, crontab

Написал модуль для `Bitrix` с использованием `Selenium` и `geckodriver` в частности. Использую php-библиотеку `php-webdriver`.

При установке модуля в систему создается агент. Агенты выполняются по крону (при переводе агентов на крон делал все по инструкции с курсов разработчика Битрикса).

После установки модуля обнаружил что мой агент не выполняется. Начал копать и пришел к тому, что при попытке запустить процесс `geckodriver` выдается исключение

`File is not executable. Make sure the path is correct or use environment variable to specify location of the executable. ("geckodriver")`.

Что делать в этом случае? Сам `geckodriver` в системе установлен. Права на него установил `777`, владельцем поставил пользователя `bitrix`.

До этого агенты запускались на хитах и этот агент отлично запускал `geckodriver`.

Также проверял вызов функции, которая вызывается в агенте. Вызывал ее через консоль и через браузер (открывал страницу). В первом и во втором случае все работает хорошо.

В чем может быть причина такого поведения, и как это исправить?

Comment: Текст ошибки что Вы указали, однозначно говорит о том, что исполняемый файл `geckodriver` который нужен `selenium` при старте не найден. Предположу, что когда Вы запускаете свой скрипт из-под своего пользователя драйвер находится по переменным окружения или лежит прямо там же где и  скрипт. А вот когда Вы запускаете его из `cron` скрипт запускается из-под другого пользователя и соответственно не может найти этот драйвер. Попробуйте в скрипте при инициализации `selenium` указать полный путь к драйверу.

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин , да, действительно, видимо дело было в переменных окружения, спасибо

Comment: Не за что. Рад, если мог ответ Вам помог.